# Update breaks site, htaccess rules, and third party add-ons

Tags: add-on, error, codeigniter, updating, core

I've updated from 2.7.2 to 2.8.1 for a new project by running the installer update. Once that finishes I get two different errors.

First, if I try to access the site at domain.com I get

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to initialize ExpressionEngine. The EE core does not appear to be defined in your autoload file. For more information please contact technical support.
```

Second, if I try to access the admin at domain.com/admin/index.php I get

```
url: http://domain.com/admin/?/cp/login%3freturn=

Disallowed Key Characters.
```

I can change the admin/index.php to admin/admin.php and login fine. However, the site still produces the core error. I've applied [this fix](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20192/when-uri_protocol-is-path_info-cant-log-into-control-panel-disallowed-key-c) to the core file and still no resolution.

All third party add-ons produce an error when trying to access them as well. If I try to access Structure or Low Variables, or really any other add-on I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in *pathname/*
```

Comment: Did you follow the usual [update procedure](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html)? Were there any errors along the way? It sounds like the updater didn't complete for some reason so I'd probably run it again. If that doesn't work then I'd roll back to your back-up before trying again.

Comment: Yep, definitely did. I'll try it again to see if anything changes. What a bummer.

Comment: Just an update if anyone is out there. Redoing the update 100% by the book, removing config_bootstrap.php and moving to a normal structure still does not solve this issue.